# Trouble downloading files in Google Apps Script web app after Chrome update

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, sandbox

I've had a Google Apps Script web app running for a bit over a year which gave users an option to download a csv file. It worked perfectly fine, although in the console it gave a warning about downloading from an iFrame being deprecated.

After updating Chrome, I now get the following error when trying to download:

> Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the
>   download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280 for more
>   details.

When following the above link, it provides the following information:

> Chrome is planning on removing this capability - i.e. Chrome is going
>   to block all downloads initiated from or instantiated in a sandboxed
>   iframe by default. The embedder may add "allow-downloads" to the
>   sandbox attributes list to opt in. This allows content providers to
>   restrict malicious or abusive downloads.

How can I add "allow-downloads" to the sandbox attributes in the Google Apps Script environment? Alternatively, is there a workaround to enable downloading files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update as of 07/29/2020:**

The attribute "allow-downloads" has now been added to the sandbox attributes and there is no longer any issue downloading files.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157368720#comment76

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is fixed right now, the iframe in GAS has been updated with `allow-downloads` flag

Answer (score 6):

It is discussed here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157368720 that `HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL` should set `allow-downloads` on GAS web app sandbox. We should watch this issue for changes.

Comment: var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page')
       html.ssid = 'hellothere';
       html.reportid = "0";
       var new_html = html.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)

IS THIS THE CORRECT SYNTAX?

Answer (score 3):

Include `sandbox="allow-downloads"` in your `iframe` tag, which contains the code that is used for downloading the CSV file.

Comment: This is not possible in a Google Apps Script web app.

Answer (score 1):

There is one work around that I found if you have a download button, you can right click and open in a new tab.  You have to rename the file but at least you can get it, until there is a fix.

Comment: please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I'm using sheets and creating a Json file. I just created a modal that retrieves the data to download, in my case its a JSON, Then turn it into a blob then a URL, then attach it to an anchor tag and display that in the modal.  Right click and open in a new tab and the download comes through, just not the name of the file that was set.

Comment: Could you please reply to my question asked here. people there does not seem to understand the actual problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698639/how-to-download-my-html-table-data-into-googlesheets-or-csv-using-javascript/62809345#62809345) also I am unable to get the result if you could provide any solution there I would greatly appreciate.